# Differential equations with jump conditions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Suppose I want to solve an ODE with a `DiracDelta` source term. In the following example, `DSolve` does it correctly while `NDSolve` (understandably) misses the Delta and provides the solution corresponding to a zero right hand side:

```
ex = y /. First[DSolve[{y'[x] + y[x] == DiracDelta[x - 1], y[2] == 1}, y, x]];
nu = y /. First[NDSolve[{y'[x] + y[x] == DiracDelta[x - 1] , y[2] == 1}, y, {x, 0.1, 2}]];
Plot[ex[t], {t, 0.9, 1.1}]
Plot[nu[t], {t, 0.9, 1.1}]
```

`Plot` of `DSolve` solution

[image: Plot of DSolve solution]

`Plot` of `NDSolve` Solution

[image]

Is there anyway around this using `NDSolve` (without converting the system to integral form)? I'd be happy to lend `NDSolve` a hand, say by telling it to look for a piecewise continuous solution (`{x,0.1,1,2}`) and provide jump conditions (in the above example `y(1+eps) - y(1-eps) == 1`).

(`DSolve` does not solve the real equations I am really interested in...  they are multidimensional, nonlinear, and a bit too messy to replicate here).

Comment: Which version are you using ?

Comment: version 8.(0.4.0)

Comment: If possible, consider switching to `Mathematica 9`, there are capabilites to handle such problems in a seamless way. Take a look at this http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/advanced-hybrid-and-differential-algebraic-equations/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can't switch to Mathematica 9, then for numerical purposes it may be good enough to approximate the delta function by a strongly peaked, normalized function. The normal distribution is one that comes to mind:

```
nu = With[{ε = .0001}, 
   y /. First[
     NDSolve[{y'[x] + y[x] == 
        PDF[NormalDistribution[1, ε], x], y[2] == 1}, 
      y, {x, 0.1, 2}, MaxStepSize -> ε, 
      MaxSteps -> Infinity]]];

Plot[nu[t], {t, 0.9, 1.1}]
```

[image: nu]

Comment: +1. Was unaware of this ability of `NDSolve`, as well as your answer.